# put a custom Class in Android hash

Tags: java, android

How can I store all content of my custom Class variable into android hash what is better to use `hashSet` or `TreeSet` and how I can do that?

A class:

```
public Album(String album, String artist, String editora, int ano, int evaluation) {
    this.album = album;
    this.artist = artist;
    this.ano = ano;
    this.evaluation = evaluation;
    this.editora = editora;
}

public List<Album> mAlbumList = new ArrayList<>();
```

I need to store full content of mAlbumList into hash and then restore when application is stopped (such as when the screen rotates).

Answer (score 1):

1. Implement hashCode and equals functions, in Android studio can autogenerate for you
2. HashSet and TreeSet are both good, depends how you are going to use it, that's where win/loss time/space comes to place

Comment: Hello!
I need to store full content of mAlbumList into hash and then restore when application is stopped (screen rorating basically)

Comment: @IvanDunets Probably better to use a SQLite database to persistently store that data instead of in memory

Comment: Implement the Parcelable interface in your custom class/object, and override the onSaveInstanceState method in your Activity and put something like (cant remember exactly) outstate.putParcelableArraylist(yourlist, "string_key"); and retrieve in onCreate - useful for small lists, but not too practical if your lists are large - you'll hit the system limit for Parcelable objects.

Comment: @cricket_007 probably yes... but I  can't... it's for my hightschool project... I need to use hashSet or TreeSet :X It is a obligatory criteria

Comment: Please refer to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()

Comment: Your project does not make sense - using a TreeSet or HashSet is irrelevant when it comes to persisting data through Android Activity lifecycle methods especially as you've already declared an Arraylist to hold your objects? Remove the ArrayList, use a hashset to hold your objects and you can put the set into SharedPreferences - putStringSet() anytime on, or after onPause(), and retrieve in onCreate(), or onResume();